# Unable to update my Developer Story: seems to be an error in the HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I am unable to update my Developer Story. When I click continue on either Work Experience or Education, I am notified that "All fields are required" and that 2 technologies are required for "Which technologies are you using there".

I have tried listing four technologies and then only two, but the field does not recognize any valid pre-configured form entries.

The console log reports two errors:

(1) Assertion failed: Input element is not an HTMLInputElement

(2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined at SetFieldValue

Seems to me like there is a mismatch between the class-name for the pre-selected field data and what is permitted within the form. Anyone else having issues with this? I am unable to publicize my account until this is fixed.

EDIT: An update on the website has solved this bug for me.

Comment: We're in the middle of a large-scale style refactoring project, and it looks like something may have gotten missed there... or it's something completely unrelated! A fun mystery. We'll investigate. Sorry about the inconvenience, and thanks for the report.

Comment: Thanks Adam, if you can keep me posted on when you are able to fix the issue, that would be great.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce what you're seeing here, but I did find another bug along the way. It should be fixed in production now. Mind checking if it resolved your issue as well? If not, do you have any browser extensions running that might be getting in the way? Any chance you could post some screenshots of what you're seeing?

Comment: Whatever you did today fixed it just fine. Thank you for looking into this for me.

Comment: Tagging this as [[meta-tag:status-completed]] since you indicated that it is now working. If that changes, please ping me or Adam in a comment so we can update this.